# Possible to check .onion link as when pinging a normal link?

Tags: python, url, ping, tor

I was wondering if this is possible:
Can I check if a port is up on one of my servers using this:

```
try:
 urllib2.urlopen('http://1.555.666.3(ip):1720(port)', timeout=1)
 return True
```

But would it work if I just replaced the ip address with a .onion address and of course replaced the port with a port listening on that .onion address.
The thing is that normal web browsers can't reach these links right...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: you would probably have to install a tor proxy and ping over that. or use [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)?

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks.